# Split String and convert results to int

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to split a string and convert the results to integers. Is there an easy way to do this?
Here is what I have now:

```
itemsA = items_str.split("|");
```

This returns an array with strings, now I need to convert them to integers. 
I don't think I can use a "for each" because the string has some undefined values (see the example below)

The original array may look like this:

```
tmp_arr = new Array();
tmp_arr[1] = 4;
tmp_arr[3] = 5;

items_str = tmp_arr.join("|");
```

Notice that tmp_arr[0] and tmp_arr[2] are not defined.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
itemsA = itemsA.map(makeInt);

protected function makeInt(value:String, index:int, array:Array):Number {
    return parseInt(value);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks :) I never knew about `array.map` , and `for each` wasn't appropriate here. Thanks a lot :))

Answer (score 0):

you should give the radix : 10

```
protected function makeInt(value:String, index:int, array:Array):Number {
    return parseInt(value, 10);
}
```

if you convert a string like "0128" you will have *bad* surprise.